# Group By resultados diferentes

Tags: sql, mysqli, group-by

Olá, tenho uma duvida se alguém puder me ajudar sobre SQL.
Eu conheço a clausula Group By, até aonde sei ela agrupar dados semelhantes.
Mas eu entendo que ele deveria agrupar mas no script abaixo ele quanto tem o group by mostra linhas e sem o group by ele mostra apenas uma linhas.
Ele não era so para agrupar, achei que ele serviria para algo mais estético!!!

**Com Group By**

```
select p.descricao
from projeto p
join depto d on p.cod_depto = d.cod_depto 
join empregado e on e.cod_depto = d.cod_depto
group by p.descricao 
having count(e.mat)>1;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Sem Group By**

```
select p.descricao
from projeto p
join depto d on p.cod_depto = d.cod_depto 
join empregado e on e.cod_depto = d.cod_depto
having count(e.mat)>1;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema na sua `query` não é o `GROUP BY` e sim o `HAVING`.

O `GROUP BY` serve para agrupar, o `HAVING` faz uma restrição baseada em alguma função agregada.

No caso da sua segunda `query` você está filtrando todos os resultados que tem `COUNT` maior que 2, porém como não houve agrupamento, portanto um agrupamento implícito é considerado.

Traduzindo a sua primeira `query`: Busque a descrição de todos os projetos que tem ao menos 2 empregados cadastrados nos departamentos relacionados a ele.

Traduzindo a sua segunda `query`: Busque a descrição de todos os projetos que tem ao menos 1 registro na mesma linha, porém considere a junção de todas elas.

Percebe como a segunda `query` não faz sentido por conta da restrição? Pois bem, ela está incorreta.

Answer (score 6):

Na segunda query você está utilizando o `HAVING` para filtrar. Mas o `HAVING` é para realizar filtros após o `GROUP BY`. Portanto nesse caso ele está assumindo que é para fazer o agrupamento sem nenhuma condição, reduzindo tudo para um único registro.

O recomendado na segunda query é a utilização do `WHERE`, que filtra os resultados antes do `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Obrigado pela força, agora entendi, alias, lembrei dos estudos da época da faculdade. Aproveitei e achei meus materiais antigos da facu e estou refazendo os estudos por ele, achei mais completo que alguns livros, minha professora de DB era o bicho hehehheheheh!!! Vlw!!!!

Comment: @Hugo caso a resposta tenha lhe auxiliado, marque-a como escolhida para que pessoas com dúvida similar possam se beneficiar também